# Waiting for all images to load in HTML error before JavaScript detects if some of them is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new at JavaScript, but was asked to create an script capable of monitoring the state of some images in a webpage. The idea of this code is to, in the HTML page, create a paragraph which content changes if some specific errors are detect. One of the errors it should detect is in case an image is missing. Below, I have first the HTML document, followed by the JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1><b>A small boy</b></h1>

        <img id="puppyimage" src="puppy.jpg" width="600" height="399">

        <img id="puppy2image" src="puppay2.jpg" width="600" height="399" >

        <p>That does not want to be disconnected.</p>

        <!-- This script is just an error searcher. -->
        <script src="C:\\Users\\dev2\\Desktop\\errodetector.js"></script>

        <!-- And now it is done. -->

    </body>

</html>
```

And the JS file:

```
var error_status = document.createElement("p");
var status_text = document.createTextNode("Everything is running smoothly");
error_status.appendChild(status_text);
error_status.style.display = "none";
error_status.id = "message";
document.body.appendChild(error_status);

function myFunction(){

    if (document.getElementById("message").innerHTML == "Everything is running smoothly"){

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Error " + "detected: "  + "Media error";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "\nError " + "detected: "  + "Media error";

    }

}


$(window).on('load', function() {

    var all_images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for (var cont = 0; cont < all_images.length ; cont++){

        all_images[cont].addEventListener("error", myFunction.bind());

    }

});

window.onerror = function(errorMsg){

    if (document.getElementById("message").innerHTML == "Everything is running smoothly"){

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Error " + "detected: "  + errorMsg +"\n";

    } else {

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "\nError " + "detected: "  + errorMsg +"\n";

    }

}
```

The image puppay2.jpg doesn't actually exists, making the web console return `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. But the paragraph I created through the script, though, keeps showing the message "Everything is running smoothly", no matter what.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 2):

The `img` tag has an [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onerror) event, but it seems like the img would fail and hit that event before you attach the event listener. So myFunction() is never called.

What you can do is add `onerror` to your `img` tags and have it point to your myFunction. I cleaned up that function a bit, for example, used jQuery instead to be consistent. And `show()` the `p` tag after adding an error.

```js
var error_status = document.createElement("p");
var status_text = document.createTextNode("Everything is running smoothly");
error_status.appendChild(status_text);
error_status.style.display = "none";
error_status.id = "message";
document.body.appendChild(error_status);

function myFunction() {
  var $msgDiv = $("#message");
  var isRunningSmoothly = $msgDiv.text() == "Everything is running smoothly";
  
  if (isRunningSmoothly) {
    $msgDiv.text("Error " + "detected: " + "Media error");
  } else {
    $msgDiv.text($msgDiv.text() + "\nError " + "detected: " + "Media error");
  }
  $msgDiv.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><b>A small boy</b></h1>

<img id="puppyimage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Alessandro_Vittoria_-_Paolo_Veronese.jpg" onerror="myFunction(this)" height="200"/>

<img id="puppy2image" src="puppay2.jpg" onerror="myFunction(this)" height="200"/>

<p>That does not want to be disconnected.</p>
```